# Error al obtener el valor de una variable

Tags: java, variables

Tengo un problema con la obtención del dato de una variable, Sucede que estoy haciendo una función que al final de cuentas debe `sumar` de a uno sobre el valor inicial de la variable `"n"`, pero solo consigo que muestre por pantalla el valor inicial de la misma que es 1. No se que es lo que esta mal, el ámbito de la variable tal vez o no lo se. Si alguno me hace el favor de ver mi error seria de mucha ayuda. Adjunto el código debajo. Gracias.

```
public class Financiera {
public static void main(String[] args){
/*  se desea conocer el valor de n */
    double n=1;
    for(double c=9500; c==0; n+=1){
        double z=Math.pow(1.018,n);
        c=c*z;
        c=c-360.84;
    }   
    System.out.println("La cantidad de cuotas son "+n);
  }
}
```

Comment: Muestra 1 dado que nunca entra al `for` y por lo tanto no se hace el aumento de la variable `n` , sería mucho mejor que expusieras que resultado deseas obtener o de qué trata tu ejercicio.

Comment: pienso que el error esta en `c==0` pues c es 9500, pues no cumple la condicion para entrar o seguir, trate de poner `c > 0` o algo asi segun lo que quiera hacer.Saludos

Comment: Lo puedes mejorar en for(double c= 9500; c==0; c=c-360.84){ // operaciones... n+=1}

Comment: Lo que intento hacer que el codigo ejecute es una funcion exponencial que dado un valor inicial de `c` se capitalice en cada periodo `n` y se le reste el pago de una cuota de $360,84, y sobre el nuevo valor de `c` se capitalice otra vez y asi sucesivamente. El ejercicio deberia arrojar al final la cantidad de periodos `n` correspondientes que transcurrieron hasta que `c` se reduzca a 0. Es por eso que la condicion que coloco para que salga del bucle es `c==0`, ya probe con `c<=0` . Es lo que quiero hacer. Tal vez el planteo esta mal y no se resuelve por eso.

Answer (score 3):

pienso que el error esta en `c==0` en la condicion del `for` pues c es 9500, pues no cumple la condicion para entrar o seguir,

con lo que al no entrar al mostrarse esta linea `System.out.println("La cantidad de cuotas son "+n);` el valor de `n` es el inicial osea 1.

trate de poner `c > 0` o algo asi segun lo que quiera hacer, por otro lado he mirado el resultado en ideone y sus operaciones sobre `c` mandan el valor al infinito quizas deba revisar eso.

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        /*  se desea conocer el valor de n */
    double n=1;
    for(double c=9500; c > 0; n+=1){
        double z=Math.pow(1.018,n);
        c=c*z;
        c=c-360.84;
        System.out.println("Valor de c por iteracion "+c);
    }   
    System.out.println("La cantidad de cuotas son "+n);

    }
}
```

ideone test -> http://ideone.com/wjlwy6

```
Valor de c por iteracion 9310.16
Valor de c por iteracion 9287.50225184
Valor de c por iteracion 9437.268990341281
Valor de c por iteracion 9774.479551860833
Valor de c por iteracion 10325.587221822174
Valor de c por iteracion 11131.313748669832
Valor de c por iteracion 12251.070206096165
Valor de c por iteracion 13769.618459072926
Valor de c por iteracion 15806.996498402385
Valor de c por iteracion 18533.300351003658
Valor de c por iteracion 22190.809963304688
Valor de c por iteracion 27127.371913836312
Valor de c por iteracion 33847.25074338676
Valor de c por iteracion 43089.41111297046
Valor de c por iteracion 55949.3806089224
Valor de c por iteracion 74071.1672507546
Valor de c por iteracion 99953.12913850415
Valor de c por iteracion 137441.4385728867
Valor de c por iteracion 192536.16035568088
Valor de c por iteracion 274724.76624405954
Valor de c por iteracion 399216.77518712974
Valor de c por iteracion 590737.7156839169
Valor de c por iteracion 890056.468119565
Valor de c por iteracion 1365367.220553743
Valor de c por iteracion 2132408.6638836376
Valor de c por iteracion 3390521.0776845836
Valor de c por iteracion 5488174.369561053
Valor de c por iteracion 9043746.02431452
Valor de c por iteracion 1.5171327737970026E7
Valor de c por iteracion 2.590901377096453E7
Valor de c por iteracion 4.504312576710311E7
Valor de c por iteracion 7.971782682515195E7
Valor de c por iteracion 1.4362532812260494E8
Valor de c por iteracion 2.6342372761165997E8
Valor de c por iteracion 4.9184334835692495E8
Valor de c por iteracion 9.34860139597317E8
Valor de c por iteracion 1.8088990979774804E9
Valor de c por iteracion 3.5631151867013283E9
Valor de c por iteracion 7.144851098269145E9
Valor de c por iteracion 1.4584928070564238E10
Valor de c por iteracion 3.0308412156864117E10
Valor de c por iteracion 6.411650753922139E10
Valor de c por iteracion 1.3807794376313095E11
Valor de c por iteracion 3.0270984275829596E11
Valor de c por iteracion 6.755796393115302E11
Valor de c por iteracion 1.5348796928455325E12
Valor de c por iteracion 3.549930954640416E12
Valor de c por iteracion 8.3582094540385E12
Valor de c por iteracion 2.003338661035112E13
Valor de c por iteracion 4.8881359070293164E13
Valor de c por iteracion 1.2141712645204561E14
Valor de c por iteracion 3.070184016169313E14
Valor de c por iteracion 7.903084771994545E14
Valor de c por iteracion 2.0709835651194255E15
Valor de c por iteracion 5.524645838487231E15
Valor de c por iteracion 1.5003065680270944E16
Valor de c por iteracion 4.1476619885156176E16
Valor de c por iteracion 1.167278484522288E17
Valor de c por iteracion 3.3442087792037658E17
Valor de c por iteracion 9.7534904415060595E17
Valor de c por iteracion 2.8958397202663183E18
Valor de c por iteracion 8.7525934587294433E18
Valor de c por iteracion 2.693064597759906E19
Valor de c por iteracion 8.435378276415717E19
Valor de c por iteracion 2.6897389556296178E20
Valor de c por iteracion 8.730989802452235E20
Valor de c por iteracion 2.8851248207880126E21
Valor de c por iteracion 9.705401606716522E21
Valor de c por iteracion 3.3236110418170043E22
Valor de c por iteracion 1.158656368834542E23
Valor de c por iteracion 4.111941157688657E23
Valor de c por iteracion 1.4855487467025852E24
Valor de c por iteracion 5.463547225251074E24
Valor de c por iteracion 2.045550818785643E25
Valor de c por iteracion 7.79639121501158E25
Valor de c por iteracion 3.0249956293845182E26
Valor de c por iteracion 1.194823229739879E27
Valor de c por iteracion 4.8043024661414146E27
Valor de c por iteracion 1.9665491430593457E28
Valor de c por iteracion 8.194586496979263E28
Valor de c por iteracion 3.4761384203978914E29
Valor de c por iteracion 1.501118087168965E30
Valor de c por iteracion 6.59903500210014E30
Valor de c por iteracion 2.953206284777373E31
Valor de c por iteracion 1.3454108138706794E32
Valor de c por iteracion 6.239701615915122E32
Valor de c por iteracion 2.945917010599056E33
Valor de c por iteracion 1.4158751914359362E34
Valor de c por iteracion 6.927510844400126E34
Valor de c por iteracion 3.450461884759912E35
Valor de c por iteracion 1.7495446575742873E36
Valor de c por iteracion 9.030683224668595E36
Valor de c por iteracion 4.745303153935823E37
Valor de c por iteracion 2.5383709835535795E38
Valor de c por iteracion 1.3822735719653705E39
Valor de c por iteracion 7.662680059202694E39
Valor de c por iteracion 4.324293460022452E40
Valor de c por iteracion 2.484262037828673E41
Valor de c por iteracion 1.4528722373691057E42
Valor de c por iteracion 8.649783254274515E42
Valor de c por iteracion 5.242407824522597E43
Valor de c por iteracion 3.234477684878983E44
Valor de c por iteracion 2.0315396048077608E45
Valor de c por iteracion 1.298955297336025E46
Valor de c por iteracion 8.454947114853072E46
Valor de c por iteracion 5.602416127566405E47
Valor de c por iteracion 3.779093260876878E48
Valor de c por iteracion 2.595061375146307E49
Valor de c por iteracion 1.8140758248764394E50
Valor de c por iteracion 1.29095473820286E51
Valor de c por iteracion 9.352212665386038E51
Valor de c por iteracion 6.897083915881683E52
Valor de c por iteracion 5.178028352553909E53
Valor de c por iteracion 3.9574106317829685E54
Valor de c por iteracion 3.078970913907674E55
Valor de c por iteracion 2.4386407933456853E56
Valor de c por iteracion 1.966246037650183E57
Valor de c por iteracion 1.6138964434470101E58
Valor de c por iteracion 1.3485319693169162E59
Valor de c por iteracion 1.1470823746389892E60
Valor de c por iteracion 9.932892717564983E60
Valor de c por iteracion 8.755977983670204E61
Valor de c por iteracion 7.857445094580631E62
Valor de c por iteracion 7.178039222234619E63
Valor de c por iteracion 6.67541203176615E64
Valor de c por iteracion 6.31972390421341E65
Valor de c por iteracion 6.09068180601701E66
Valor de c por iteracion 5.975599681575902E67
Valor de c por iteracion 5.968220465321187E68
Valor de c por iteracion 6.0681456681054064E69
Valor de c por iteracion 6.280799296950458E70
Valor de c por iteracion 6.617921507092951E71
Valor de c por iteracion 7.09865526622127E72
Valor de c por iteracion 7.75136768428979E73
Valor de c por iteracion 8.616449919140563E74
Valor de c por iteracion 9.75048405044733E75
Valor de c por iteracion 1.1232379347898049E77
Valor de c por iteracion 1.3172406556971471E78
Valor de c por iteracion 1.57255653795416E79
Valor de c por iteracion 1.911151821305684E80
Valor de c por iteracion 2.364459539261323E81
Valor de c por iteracion 2.9779428770583413E82
Valor de c por iteracion 3.818111588352773E83
Valor de c por iteracion 4.983433290565111E84
Valor de c por iteracion 6.621501155477478E85
Valor de c por iteracion 8.956370426875736E86
Valor de c por iteracion 1.233262180100717E88
Valor de c por iteracion 1.7287275670379736E89
Valor de c por iteracion 2.4668655474436453E90
Valor de c por iteracion 3.583539366531844E91
Valor de c por iteracion 5.299399468316096E92
Valor de c por iteracion 7.977905982236706E93
Valor de c por iteracion 1.2226409795731374E95
Valor de c por iteracion 1.907465800786092E96
Valor de c por iteracion 3.0294399640708226E97
Valor de c por iteracion 4.897965462335181E98
Valor de c por iteracion 8.061518677358233E99
Valor de c por iteracion 1.3507214249483696E101
Valor de c por iteracion 2.3038939842087563E102
Valor de c por iteracion 4.000432720987127E103
Valor de c por iteracion 7.07129945301376E104
Valor de c por iteracion 1.2724457195422477E106
Valor de c por iteracion 2.330918448721855E107
Valor de c por iteracion 4.3467300681747585E108
Valor de c por iteracion 8.251749612802547E109
Valor de c por iteracion 1.594693373531634E111
Valor de c por iteracion 3.1373004783975787E112
Valor de c por iteracion 6.283228008162585E113
Valor de c por iteracion 1.2810241051163907E115
Valor de c por iteracion 2.658762606356189E116
Valor de c por iteracion 5.617584324105567E117
Valor de c por iteracion 1.2082795254878315E119
Valor de c por iteracion 2.6456537817268474E120
Valor de c por iteracion 5.897207138951151E121
Valor de c por iteracion 1.3381584249962972E123
Valor de c por iteracion 3.0911242405159564E124
Valor de c por iteracion 7.268974862672004E125
Valor de c por iteracion 1.7401137996690188E127
Valor de c por iteracion 4.240625428865257E128
Valor de c por iteracion 1.0520344303874597E130
Valor de c por iteracion 2.656915678098762E131
Valor de c por iteracion 6.830828278547708E132
Valor de c por iteracion 1.787790980046282E134
Valor de c por iteracion 4.763299550573159E135
Valor de c por iteracion 1.29195332526207E137
Valor de c por iteracion 3.56724988155545E138
Valor de c por iteracion 1.0026930814813954E140
Valor de c por iteracion 2.869130369656328E141
Valor de c por iteracion 8.357575808849603E142
Valor de c por iteracion 2.478324354790383E144
Valor de c por iteracion 7.481414945542297E145
Valor de c por iteracion 2.299096069883712E147
Valor de c por iteracion 7.192473545468705E148
Valor de c por iteracion 2.2905891821898352E150
Valor de c por iteracion 7.426153389689254E151
Valor de c por iteracion 2.4509158682279143E153
Valor de c por iteracion 8.234565146874297E154
Valor de c por iteracion 2.816441363402358E156
Valor de c por iteracion 9.806375885813016E157
Valor de c por iteracion 3.475874890569093E159
Valor de c por iteracion 1.2542020732929531E161
Valor de c por iteracion 4.607004861218991E162
Valor de c por iteracion 1.722731539010296E164
Valor de c por iteracion 6.557892856011436E165
Valor de c por iteracion 2.5413167969789424E167
Valor de c por iteracion 1.0025385357901274E169
Valor de c por iteracion 4.0261608479664354E170
Valor de c por iteracion 1.645996644090982E172
Valor de c por iteracion 6.850378178244672E173
Valor de c por iteracion 2.90233759696898E175
Valor de c por iteracion 1.251783105565567E177
Valor de c por iteracion 5.496142978081173E178
Valor de c por iteracion 2.456601633000667E180
Valor de c por iteracion 1.1177874477175799E182
Valor de c por iteracion 5.177635800601072E183
Valor de c por iteracion 2.441470868553454E185
Valor de c por iteracion 1.171977766633688E187
Valor de c por iteracion 5.727102778215189E188
Valor de c por iteracion 2.8490387697650607E190
Valor de c por iteracion 1.442811247855551E192
Valor de c por iteracion 7.438210377383309E193
Valor de c por iteracion 3.903688665239697E195
Valor de c por iteracion 2.0855935153168416E197
Valor de c por iteracion 1.1343104679840392E199
Valor de c por iteracion 6.280323142734697E200
Valor de c por iteracion 3.539808911974446E202
Valor de c por iteracion 2.0310724928938339E204
Valor de c por iteracion 1.186366319286025E206
Valor de c por iteracion 7.054398202589499E207
Valor de c por iteracion 4.270206831495244E209
Valor de c por iteracion 2.6313924796366243E211
Valor de c por iteracion 1.6507075031524782E213
Valor de c por iteracion 1.0541499670335349E215
Valor de c por iteracion 6.853027138910698E216
Valor de c por iteracion 4.5353445068717886E218
Valor de c por iteracion 3.055525341997801E220
Valor de c por iteracion 2.095604277309224E222
Valor de c por iteracion 1.463121662516165E224
Valor de c por iteracion 1.0399186873726409E226
Valor de c por iteracion 7.524299997225394E227
Valor de c por iteracion 5.542179670020881E229
Valor de c por iteracion 4.155687453348407E231
Valor de c por iteracion 3.1721442725492955E233
Valor de c por iteracion 2.4649650359916276E235
Valor de c por iteracion 1.9499181135939287E237
Valor de c por iteracion 1.5702534700901303E239
Valor de c por iteracion 1.28727379376443E241
Valor de c por iteracion 1.074285891422275E243
Valor de c por iteracion 9.126759244048685E244
Valor de c por iteracion 7.893345169407555E246
Valor de c por iteracion 6.949497015395646E248
Valor de c por iteracion 6.228642846552344E250
Valor de c por iteracion 5.683047200853795E252
Valor de c por iteracion 5.278577172569663E254
Valor de c por iteracion 4.991145902837837E256
Valor de c por iteracion 4.804314546885925E258
Valor de c por iteracion 4.707717348202048E260
Valor de c por iteracion 4.6960974885661155E262
Valor de c por iteracion 4.768827423313596E264
Valor de c por iteracion 4.929852056861129E266
Valor de c por iteracion 5.188047511434687E268
Valor de c por iteracion 5.558041444352366E270
Valor de c por iteracion 6.061601685870168E272
Valor de c por iteracion 6.729778761566809E274
Valor de c por iteracion 7.606098712546887E276
Valor de c por iteracion 8.751266421802251E278
Valor de c por iteracion 1.0250088893599739E281
Valor de c por iteracion 1.2221714546607377E283
Valor de c por iteracion 1.4834892999802094E285
Valor de c por iteracion 1.8330929131661602E287
Valor de c por iteracion 2.3058567133952596E289
Valor de c por iteracion 2.95275853019903E291
Valor de c por iteracion 3.849207532705712E293
Valor de c por iteracion 5.108136561427127E295
Valor de c por iteracion 6.900831916397159E297
Valor de c por iteracion 9.490479985388676E299
Valor de c por iteracion 1.3286869938326022E302
Valor de c por iteracion 1.8936729171161662E304
Valor de c por iteracion 2.747483103297028E306
Valor de c por iteracion Infinity
Valor de c por iteracion Infinity
Valor de c por iteracion Infinity
```

---

El ambito segun entiendo lo que quiere hacer esta bien, pues esta no varia en su ejemplo por lo mencionado de no entrar en el `for` aqui tiene una pequeña pararte de lo que muestra si tratamos de imprimir el valor de `n` desde dentro del `for` del ejemplo anterior:

```
Valor de c por iteracion 9310.16
Valor de n por iteracion 1.0
Valor de c por iteracion 9287.50225184
Valor de n por iteracion 2.0
Valor de c por iteracion 9437.268990341281
Valor de n por iteracion 3.0
Valor de c por iteracion 9774.479551860833
Valor de n por iteracion 4.0
Valor de c por iteracion 10325.587221822174
Valor de n por iteracion 5.0
Valor de c por iteracion 11131.313748669832
Valor de n por iteracion 6.0
Valor de c por iteracion 12251.070206096165
Valor de n por iteracion 7.0
Valor de c por iteracion 13769.618459072926
Valor de n por iteracion 8.0
Valor de c por iteracion 15806.996498402385
Valor de n por iteracion 9.0
Valor de c por iteracion 18533.300351003658
Valor de n por iteracion 10.0
Valor de c por iteracion 22190.809963304688
Valor de n por iteracion 11.0
Valor de c por iteracion 27127.371913836312
Valor de n por iteracion 12.0
//...
Valor de c por iteracion Infinity
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Estaré viendo como resolverlo.

Answer (score 2):

Acabo de leer su comentario en su pregunta:

*Lo que intento hacer que el codigo ejecute es una funcion exponencial que dado un valor inicial de c se capitalice en cada periodo n y se le reste el pago de una cuota de $360,84, y sobre el nuevo valor de c...*

> quizas eso seria para crear otra pregunta (aconsejo que lo haga), pues
>   ya no se trata del error que respondia anteriormente, y esta pidiendo
>   ayuda para otra cosa;

Aun asi le dejare este codigo por si ayuda en lo que busca (es posible que pasado un tiempo lo borre), no se muy bien lo que esta intando conseguir pero ajustandome a su codigo quizas esto sea mas o menos lo que busca, tenga en cuenta lo que se cometa debajo sobre, pues 360.84 puede no ser exacto, para la ultima n, con lo que tendria que "devolver" o trabajar esa parte, se le resta -1 a n al final porque aunque no pudiera entrar en el for previamente se a aunmetado el valor a n.

---

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        /*  se desea conocer el valor de n */
    double n=1;
    double c_final = 0;
    for(double c=9500; c > 0; n+=1){
        double z=Math.pow(1.018,n);

        c=c+z;
        c -= 360.84;

        c_final = c;

        System.out.println("Valor de c por iteracion "+c);
        System.out.println("Valor de n por iteracion "+n);
    }
    System.out.println("tener en cuenta que cuando entra en la ultima iteracion c es mayor que 0 pero con las operaciones de dentro c puede aignar negativo por ejemplo " +c_final);
    System.out.println("La cantidad de cuotas son "+(n-1));

    }
}
```

---

```
Valor de c por iteracion 9140.178
Valor de n por iteracion 1.0
Valor de c por iteracion 8780.374324
Valor de n por iteracion 2.0
Valor de c por iteracion 8420.589301832
Valor de n por iteracion 3.0
Valor de c por iteracion 8060.823269264976
Valor de n por iteracion 4.0
Valor de c por iteracion 7701.0765681117455
Valor de n por iteracion 5.0
Valor de c por iteracion 7341.349546337757
Valor de n por iteracion 6.0
Valor de c por iteracion 6981.642558171836
Valor de n por iteracion 7.0
Valor de c por iteracion 6621.955964218929
Valor de n por iteracion 8.0
Valor de c por iteracion 6262.2901315748695
Valor de n por iteracion 9.0
Valor de c por iteracion 5902.645433943217
Valor de n por iteracion 10.0
Valor de c por iteracion 5543.022251754194
Valor de n por iteracion 11.0
Valor de c por iteracion 5183.4209722857695
Valor de n por iteracion 12.0
Valor de c por iteracion 4823.8419897869135
Valor de n por iteracion 13.0
Valor de c por iteracion 4464.285705603078
Valor de n por iteracion 14.0
Valor de c por iteracion 4104.752528303933
Valor de n por iteracion 15.0
Valor de c por iteracion 3745.242873813404
Valor de n por iteracion 16.0
Valor de c por iteracion 3385.757165542045
Valor de n por iteracion 17.0
Valor de c por iteracion 3026.2958345218017
Valor de n por iteracion 18.0
Valor de c por iteracion 2666.859319543194
Valor de n por iteracion 19.0
Valor de c por iteracion 2307.448067294971
Valor de n por iteracion 20.0
Valor de c por iteracion 1948.0625325062808
Valor de n por iteracion 21.0
Valor de c por iteracion 1588.703178091394
Valor de n por iteracion 22.0
Valor de c por iteracion 1229.370475297039
Valor de n por iteracion 23.0
Valor de c por iteracion 870.0649038523859
Valor de n por iteracion 24.0
Valor de c por iteracion 510.7869521217289
Valor de n por iteracion 25.0
Valor de c por iteracion 151.53711725992008
Valor de n por iteracion 26.0
Valor de c por iteracion -207.68409462940127
Valor de n por iteracion 27.0

tener en cuenta que cuando entra en la ultima iteracion c es mayor que 0 pero con las operaciones de dentro c puede aignar negativo por ejemplo -207.68409462940127

La cantidad de cuotas son 27.0
```

---

> UPDATE: por su perfil -> *Estudio Contador Publico Nacional*

**Por favor**, sea este ejemplo lo que usted busca (o cualquier otro) no, no lo utilice para hacer operaciones finacieras, sin antes asegurarse de que hace las operaciones de la manera correcta (que se espera) no basta solo con que compile, por ejemplo podria asignar a `c` un valor menor y calcularlo usted mismo para asegurarse que el resultado es el que se queria por ejemplo con `c = 1000` y tener en cuenta otras cosas como pude ser esta parte -> `double z=Math.pow(1.018,n);`
pues quizas no funciona como cree, en este caso n aumenta su valor con cada iteracion algo asi:

```
double z=Math.pow(1.018,1);
double z=Math.pow(1.018,2);
double z=Math.pow(1.018,3);
```

si eso es lo que espera genial, pero quizas quiera saber cuanto es el valor final para `n` antes de aplicar `double z=Math.pow(1.018,n);` en cada iteracion o aplicarse de cualquier otra manera ect.

Por otro lado quizas quiera mirar esta clase [`Currency`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) o [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) para representar los valores decimales en sus operaciones en este tipo de operaciones financieras.

Quizas [esta pagina](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/NUM04-J.+Do+not+use+floating-point+numbers+if+precise+computation+is+required) le sea util, donde se muestra algun ejemplo de los resultados al usar diferentes tipos de datos.

Comment: Angel ,Seria genial que editaras tu respuesta anterior y añadas este ultimo detalle.

Comment: @Dev.Joel no es mal consejo pero lo que sucede es que la respuesta anterior es para el error que comentaba en un principio, "que totalmente diferente" a lo que ahora el OP pide en los comentarios, y esta respuesta fue por ayudarle de alguna manera, pues yo no se muy bien lo que quiere lograr exactamente, mas o menos he deducido algo por su codigo, pero que puede estar  mal en esta respuesta, o de entenderlo con mas detalles podria quizas hacerse mejor, solo le mencionaba algunas cosas y que el lo mirase a ver si es lo que busca o se aproxima, mas...

Comment: @Dev.Joel ...que nada por el dia que es y quizas no este mucha gente por aqui que lo puedan ayudar mejor con lo que comenta es su comentario "pues yo no lo tengo muy claro". Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias. Sucede que estoy pasando a código una formula de interés compuesto. Lo resuelvo en papel, pero al volcarlo al código se me complico. No puedo conocer el valor de `n` ya que justamente es la incógnita. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.